# Conditional Compilation in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I currently have a make file, part of which looks like the following.

```
####################################################################
# Files                                                            #
####################################################################

C_SRC +=  \
CMSIS/CM3/CoreSupport/core_cm3.c \
CMSIS/CM3/DeviceSupport/EnergyMicro/EFM32/system_efm32.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_assert.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_system.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_gpio.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_cmu.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_usart.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_i2c.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_dma.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_timer.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_int.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_emu.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_adc.c \
efm32lib/src/efm32_rtc.c \
radio.c \
led.c \
trace.c \
    main.c


S_SRC +=  \
CMSIS/CM3/DeviceSupport/EnergyMicro/EFM32/startup/cs3/startup_efm32.s

####################################################################
# Rules                                                            #
####################################################################

C_FILES = $(notdir $(C_SRC) )
S_FILES = $(notdir $(S_SRC) )
#make list of source paths, sort also removes duplicates
C_PATHS = $(sort $(dir $(C_SRC) ) )
S_PATHS = $(sort $(dir $(S_SRC) ) )

C_OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(C_FILES:.c=.o))
S_OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(S_FILES:.s=.o))
C_DEPS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(C_FILES:.c=.d))

vpath %.c $(C_PATHS)
vpath %.s $(S_PATHS)

# Default build is debug build
all:    debug


debug:    CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -O0 -g3
debug:    $(OBJ_DIR) $(LST_DIR) $(EXE_DIR) $(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME).bin

release:  CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG -O3
release:  $(OBJ_DIR) $(LST_DIR) $(EXE_DIR) $(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME).bin

base:     CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -O0 -g3
base:     $(OBJ_DIR) $(LST_DIR) $(EXE_DIR) $(EXE_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME).bin
```

Essentially what I want to do is if it is run with the base target then I want to change the main.c file in `C_SRC` with mainbase.c

I have tried for hours and hours now and have gotten no where with it. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a simpler way, but you haven't shown us the rest of the rules, the actual recipes that build things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using GNU make then you can use directives such as `if` and similar.

See [Conditional Parts of Makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) in the documentation.

If you case you could do it like this:

```
C_SRC +=  \
CMSIS/CM3/CoreSupport/core_cm3.c \
....
led.c \
trace.c

ifeq ($(SPECIAL),"")
C_SRC += main.c
else
C_SRC += main_special.c
endif
```

The when calling `make` on the command line, if you set the variable `SPECIAL` then the file `main_special.c` will be used, otherwise `main.c` will be used.

Command line for using `main_special.c`:

```
$ make SPECIAL=1
```

Comment: With the current version of Make you need parentheses.
`ifeq ($(SPECIAL),"")`